# Not secured subdomain heroku website when I set up it as subdomain of the website from another hosting

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, heroku, dns, heroku-cli

I have an `http://example.com` website on some hosting and I'd like to have `https://myapp.herokuapp.com` being show as `https://subdomain.example.com`

I have configured on "example.com" hosting side:

CNAME myapp.herokuapp.com.

I have added to `heroku domains:add --app myapp subdomain.example.com`
So now I see CNAME like subdomain.example.com when calling for `heroku domains -a myapp`

But when I'm opening `https://subdomain.example.com` I see the insecure connection and the certificate is issued for *.herokuapp.com :

Subject:

```
CN = *.herokuapp.com
O = Heroku, Inc.
L = San Francisco
S = California
C = US
```

Alternative subject:

```
DNS Name=*.herokuapp.com
DNS Name=herokuapp.com
```

So how can I make my heroku subdomain issue a certificate for https://subdomain.example.com ?

Also, there is a problem.

When I type  **http**://**subdomain.example**.com in Chrome, the **http**://**example**.com  is loaded.
When I type  **http**://subdomain.example.com in Firefox, the **http**://subdomain.example.com  is loaded and works without any encryption, while it doesn't allow to open **http**://myapp.herokuapp.com and opens it as **https**://myapp.herokuapp.com

How can I avoid this behavior in Firefox? The behavior I want when trying to open **http**://subdomain.example.com is to always force **https**://subdomain.example.com and not leave to **http**://**subdomain.example**.com or redirect to **http**://**example**.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer of the Heroku support team:

Thank you for reaching out to us. Looking into your issue I found that you have configured your domain incorrectly.

```
subdomain.example.com. 599    IN      CNAME   myapp.herokuapp.com
```

When you add a domain to your app, Heroku generates a unique DNS target for that domain. You need to point your domain to this DNS target at your DNS provider.

```
=== myapp Custom Domains
Domain Name              DNS Record Type  DNS Target
───────────────────────  ───────────────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
subdomain.example.com.ru  CNAME            secure-lynx-1rbkrol1o46ccpklg1j5u2ac.herokudns.com
```

In your case, I see that you have added a subdomain subdomain.example.com to your app. You need to point your subdomain to the Heroku generated DNS target secure-lynx-1rbkrol1o46ccpklg1j5u2ac.herokudns.com of that domain with CNAME record type (CNAME for subdomains and ALIAS/ANAME for root domains) at your DNS provider. This should resolve your issue.